# Verb confusion whether to use active or passive

Tags: passive-voice, confusables, active-voice

Which of the following is correct?

computer games designed to involve many players

or

computer games were designed to involve many players

I assume the latter one is correct. Can anyone explain if it is wrong

Comment: The first is a noun phrase, and the second is an independent clause.

Comment: are they both correct?

Comment: Yes, but the meanings are different. First is sentence reduction. It is; computer games which are designed to involve many players. Second sentence however are talking about all the computer games and it says computer games were designed to involve many players which means all of them.

Comment: Actually, the original sentence is  " Computer games designed to involve many players at once have proliferated; such games were 
first developed before the widespread availability of high-speed internet connections." So which one is real "verb." I am confused here.

Comment: *Designed*, *have proliferated*, and *were developed* are all "real" verbs.  Only the last two are finite verbs, i.e., those that form predicates for clauses.  The first is a participial adjective, modifying *computer games*.

Comment: Sorry, but I missed *to involve*, another non-finite verb form.  This time an infinitive and acting as a complement to *designed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some punctuation or, perhaps, a conjunction.

Consider:

> "Computer games, designed to involve many players at once, have proliferated; such games were first developed before the widespread availability of high-speed internet connections."

In this sentence, '*designed*' **and** '*developed*' are verbs.

Using a conjunction (*that*), you could also structure this sentence as:

> "Computer games that are designed to involve many players at once have proliferated; such games were first developed before the widespread availability of high-speed internet connections."

The verb structure remains the same across both examples. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I doubt it helps because you've changed the meaning with the punctuation.  The OP's version talks about only some computer games, namely those that are multiplayer.  Your version talks about all computer games.

Comment: Yes, I see your argument regarding the commas. I think the conjunction leaves the original intention intact.

Comment: It leaves the meaning intact, but it changes the syntax from a non-finite clause to a finite one.

Comment: Is it okay if I didn't use comma. Will the sentence remain meaningful?